# Elasticsearch merge new document with the existing document

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to merge new document with the existing document in elasticsearch instead of override. I have below record in ES,

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "student_name": "Rahul",
  "books": [
    {
      "book_id": "11",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Started"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have received another json to process I need to update the existing document if id is same or just insert it. If I receive below json,

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "address": "Bangalore",
  "books": [
    {
      "book_id": "11",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Finished"
    },
    {
      "book_id": "12",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Started"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to have my final document like below:

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "student_name": "Rahul",
  "address": "Bangalore",
  "books": [
    {
      "book_id": "11",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Finished"
    },
    {
      "book_id": "12",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Started"
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically I want to merge the new json with the existing document if any. i.e. for any given key be it on top or nested if its there in db but not received this time I have to retain that as it is. I got any new key have to add it and if updated have to modify.
Also for the array of json inside the doc if I got same id in json I have to replace but if new json with new id, I need to append that json in the array.

I want to understand whether it is possible to via es queries if yes then want to know the way how to achieve it. Merging at application level and override I can think one way but want to know the better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an [upsert query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert).

The first piece will be indexed as new document because it doesn't exist yet:

```
POST my-index/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "id": "1",
    "student_name": "Rahul",
    "books": [
      {
        "book_id": "11",
        "book_name": "History",
        "status": "Started"
      }
    ]
  },
  "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

And the second piece will be merged with the first one because it already exists:

```
POST my-index/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "id": "1",
    "address": "Bangalore",
    "books": [
      {
        "book_id": "11",
        "book_name": "History",
        "status": "Finished"
      },
      {
        "book_id": "12",
        "book_name": "History",
        "status": "Started"
      }
    ]
  },
  "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

The document you get after the two commands will be the one you expect:

```
GET my-index/_doc/1
=> 
{
  "id": "1",
  "student_name": "Rahul",
  "address": "Bangalore",
  "books": [
    {
      "book_id": "11",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Finished"
    },
    {
      "book_id": "12",
      "book_name": "History",
      "status": "Started"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val for your quick response and suggestions.  I also want to remove retain the new older json in the array id not received this time. Let's we get third json like below
{
  "id": "1",
  "student_name": "Rahul",
  "address": "Bangalore",
  "books": [
    {
      "book_id": "13",
      "book_name": "Math",
      "status": "Finished"
    }
  ]
}
I want get appended third json the the books array as it's with the new book_id, So at the end inside books array there should be three json with book_Ids 11, 12 (previous) and 13 (new).

Comment: Ok, I see, then you need to use [scripted upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#scripted_upsert) instead and add some logic to merge the books array. Try it out

Comment: Thanks @Val, I have tried scripting but the performance was very poor so we went ahead with get-merge-reindex via application.

Comment: Yes, performance is one big downside of scripting. It's very flexible but makes everything else slower.